# How do I set something in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web so that running it in debug mode opens home page?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Running Razor, MVC5, .Net 4.5.1. I have no idea what constitutes a "start page" in MVC within the visual studio development environment.  How do I set it so that every time I run F5 my home page opens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Setting a startup page for MVC5 when debugging

This can be done in the [Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7f8bfy4(v=vs.90).aspx).

1. Open Solution Explorer and find the relevant project.

[image: Solution Explorer]

2. Right-click on the project and choose *Properties* (or press Alt+Enter).

[image: Right-click menu]

3. Navigate to Web -> Start Action.

[image: Web section]

### Explanation

By default an MVC application has the *Specific Page* radio button selected and the input box is blank. This means that the application will open a browser to the server with no page specified and MVC will use the default route of */Home/Index*.

```
http://localhost:12345/
```

You can specifiy a different route. For example you could use **Home/About** (see image).

This would open

```
http://localhost:123456/Home/About
```